# pjsua Building for Android C compiler cannot create executables error

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

When I run ./configure-android I get following error

I have read the guide from http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android
and I have gcc installed

I encountered this problem both in ubuntu and windows

---

GCC

```
root@kemal-Vostro-230:/home/kemal/Desktop/pjsua# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
```

Terminal

```
root@kemal-Vostro-230:/home/kemal/Desktop/pjsua# ./configure-android
configure-android: APP_PLATFORM not specified, using android-14
configure-android: TARGET_ABI not specified, using armeabi
configure-android: calling ./configure with env vars:
 CC = /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
 CXX = /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
 CFLAGS =  -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
 CXXFLAGS =  -shared --sysroot=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
 LDFLAGS =  -nostdlib -L/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/
 LIBS =  -lc -lgcc
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
aconfigure: error: in `/home/kemal/Desktop/pjsua':
aconfigure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

---

Config Log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by pjproject aconfigure 2.x, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./aconfigure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-video

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = kemal-Vostro-230
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.5.0-17-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

aconfigure:2335: checking build system type
aconfigure:2349: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
aconfigure:2369: checking host system type
aconfigure:2382: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
aconfigure:2402: checking target system type
aconfigure:2415: result: arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
aconfigure:2463: checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
aconfigure:2490: result: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
aconfigure:2759: checking for C compiler version
aconfigure:2768: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --version >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

aconfigure:2779: $? = 0
aconfigure:2768: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.4.3/configure --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --without-ppl --without-cloog --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.19 --with-mpfr-version=2.4.1 --with-mpc-version=0.8.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.4.3 --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.4.3 --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --disable-bootstrap --disable-libquadmath --disable-plugin --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) 
aconfigure:2779: $? = 0
aconfigure:2768: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -V >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: '-V' option must have argument
aconfigure:2779: $? = 1
aconfigure:2768: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -qversion >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: no input files
aconfigure:2779: $? = 1
aconfigure:2799: checking whether the C compiler works
aconfigure:2821: /home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include  -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include  -nostdlib -L/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/ conftest.c  -lc -lgcc >&5
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5te'
aconfigure:2825: $? = 1
aconfigure:2863: result: no
aconfigure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
aconfigure:2868: error: in `/home/kemal/Desktop/pjsua':
aconfigure:2870: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=' -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=' -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=' -shared --sysroot=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm'
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=' -nostdlib -L/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=' -lc -lgcc'
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-linux-androideabi
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
ac_cv_prog_CC=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
ac_cv_target=arm-unknown-linux-androideabi

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
CC='/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc'
CC_CFLAGS=''
CC_DEF=''
CC_INC=''
CC_OPTIMIZE=''
CC_OUT=''
CFLAGS=' -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=' -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include'
CXX='/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++'
CXXFLAGS=' -I/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include  -shared --sysroot=/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm'
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
GREP=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=' -nostdlib -L/home/kemal/Desktop/Dev/Android/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/'
LDOUT=''
LIBEXT2=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=' -lc -lgcc'
LTLIBOBJS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='pjproject'
PACKAGE_STRING='pjproject 2.x'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='pjproject'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.x'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
RANLIB=''
SAVED_PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
ac_build_mak_vars=''
ac_cross_compile=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_external_gsm=''
ac_external_pa=''
ac_external_speex=''
ac_ffmpeg_cflags=''
ac_ffmpeg_ldflags=''
ac_has_ffmpeg=''
ac_host=''
ac_ios_cflags=''
ac_linux_poll=''
ac_main_obj=''
ac_no_g711_codec=''
ac_no_g7221_codec=''
ac_no_g722_codec=''
ac_no_gsm_codec=''
ac_no_ilbc_codec=''
ac_no_l16_codec=''
ac_no_large_filter=''
ac_no_opencore_amrnb=''
ac_no_small_filter=''
ac_no_speex_aec=''
ac_no_speex_codec=''
ac_no_ssl=''
ac_os_objs=''
ac_pa_cflags=''
ac_pa_use_alsa=''
ac_pa_use_oss=''
ac_pjdir=''
ac_pjmedia_snd=''
ac_pjmedia_video=''
ac_pjmedia_video_has_ios=''
ac_pjmedia_video_has_qt=''
ac_qt_cflags=''
ac_resample_dll=''
ac_sdl_cflags=''
ac_sdl_ldflags=''
ac_shlib_suffix=''
ac_v4l2_cflags=''
ac_v4l2_ldflags=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-unknown-linux-androideabi'
host_alias='arm-linux-androideabi'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='linux-androideabi'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libcrypto_present=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libssl_present=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
opencore_amrnb_h_present=''
opencore_amrnb_present=''
openssl_h_present=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='arm-unknown-linux-androideabi'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='arm'
target_os='linux-androideabi'
target_vendor='unknown'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

aconfigure: exit 77
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed ia32-libs `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` and everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the below steps?

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir 
$ ./configure-android
```

In export command give path with front slashes(/) only.
For example, I have written this like -

```
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e
```

Where D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e is ndk location. Use front slash only.

This solved my problem.